# Database table with thousands of columns

Tags: database-design

I write a simple Django app, that displays values from a table. 
The table is very simple, there is no relations with other tables, all values are integers:

```
patientID    region1 region2 regionN region200000
patient1          30      23       9           14
patient2           1      12       9           22
patientN          23      21      12            8
```

the only problem is that I have ~200 000 genomic regions - this is the fixed number (only number of patients is increasing).

What would be the best DB system for such table? The data is super structured, simple and homogeneous - perfect for SQL, but the amount of suggest it should be noSQL?

It would be better to have 1 table with 200000 columns, then N tables (N patients) with 200000 rows.

Answer (score 8):

That design is **not** "perfect for SQL" as it violates the basic rules of database normalization. And no relational database supports 200000 columns for a single table (most of them have a limit of around 1500 to 2000 columns)

Even if the number of regions is "fixed", in a relational database you should not have one column for each "fixed" thing.

This is a classical many-to-many relationship that is typically modeled with three tables.

One for patients and one for the regions:

```
create table patient 
( 
   id integer primary key, 
   ... other columns
);

create table region
(
   id integer primary key, 
   ... other columns
);
```

Then you need a mapping table between patients and regions:

```
create table person_region_map
(
   person_id integer not null references person,
   region_id integer not null references region,
   primary key (person_id, region_id)
);
```

The map ensures that each combination of region and person only occurs once due to the primary key on both columns.

---

Another option would be to exploit JSON functionality in a relational database which is pretty common nowadays. Whether it is usable for you depends heavily on the actual DBMS product you are using.

In PostgreSQL you could think about something like this:

```
create table patient 
( 
   id integer primary key, 
   regions jsonb,
   ... other columns
);
```

Then you would insert a JSON value that contains a key/value map for the regions. This has the added benefit that if region is not assigned to a region, it doesn't take up space:

```
insert into patient (id, regions)
values (42, '{"region1": 30, "region10": 9}');
```

With Postgres this can be indexed and queried quite efficiently.

Comment: "no relational database supports 200000 columns for a single table" - just curiosity: is there any database type that supports 200000? (not necessarily RDBMS)

Comment: @Thedam: well the concept of a "column" (that is part of a "table") is intrinsic to a relational database - so this doesn't apply to other types of databases like Key/Value stores (e.g. Redis or Riak) or document databases (like MongoDB)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use many to many relationship

[image]